# Height isn't showing up full on everything except Chrome

Tags: css, object

So, I have a page, where I have the object go 100% for width and height, and fill the container. This worked fine for me, so I went with it. I than viewed the page in firefox, and *almost* gasped. The objects had full width, but the height was squished. I am confused on how to fix this in browser besides chrome. Here's some code:

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<div class="bottombar">
<a href="/" class="menu">1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">3</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">4</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">5</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">Support</a>
<a href="#about" id="opener" class="menu">About</a>
</div>
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.google.com/" seamless></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
p {
    font-size: 30px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url('http://ptd.burngames.net/images/pattern-aosk.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.bottombar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://ptd.burngames.net/images/menuback.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font-size: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: white;
}
.menu {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-family: 'Iceland', Arial;
    color:white;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
a:active {
    color:lightgray;
}
iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
embed {
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    background-image: url('images/trans.png')
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#news {
    font-family: 'Iceland', Arial;
}
#news.h1 {
    background-color:lightred;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your html and content tags height 100% too:

```
html, #content {height:100%;}
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LUeZr/1/

Please note as you have a bottombar taking up 50px height, your iframe will will add scroll bars to your page

Comment: I think the other answer may have worked, but since this is what I tried first, and it worked, you may have the correct answer thingy thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
html{height: 100%;}
body{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```